# How to Redirect IIS 400 error to custom URL

Tags: web-config, iis-8, iis-8.5

We have a page `example.com/my-page` . by mistake, it was announced to clients as `example.com/my-page/%0D` on a PDF invitation.

When opened the server returns "HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid."

How can we redirect the wrong url to the correct url.

Comment: Please enable FRT to see where such 400 errors come from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing. You cannot override it if coming from HTTP.sys, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/error#how-to but can if from another module or handler.

Comment: Do you want to redirect from `example.com/my-page` to `example.com/my-page/%0D`? If so, please post your rule, if not, If I misunderstand your requirement, please post more details information about your requirement, I will make demo for you.

Comment: We managed to solve it from WAF F5. which was handled by other team.